# Replacing ProxyFactory with RestEasyWebTarget does not work

Tags: java, jaxb, client, jax-rs, resteasy

After upgrading from Resteasy 2.4 to 3.0.5, none of my client calls work anymore. The entity which I am expecting (as simple as a String) is always null. In debug mode I can see it being set in the Response object on the server side, but on the client side the entity in the Response is null. Here is an example call:

The interface:

```
  /**
   * @return all expired licenses
   */
  @GET
  @ClientResponseType(entityType = LicenseList.class)
  @Path("/expired")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
  public Response getExpiredLicenses();
```

The implementation:

```
  /**
   * @return all expired licenses
   */
  @Override
  public Response getExpiredLicenses() {
    try {
      LicenseList list = LicensesDBUtil.getExpiredLicenses();
      Response resp = Response.ok().entity(list).build();
      return resp;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      LOG.error("Error getting expired licenses : " + e.getMessage());
      return   Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(e.getMessage()).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }
```

The test call :

```
  @Test
  public void testGetExpiredLicenses() throws Exception {
        ResteasyClientBuilder rsb = new ResteasyClientBuilder();
    ResteasyClient rsc = rsb.build();
    ResteasyWebTarget target = rsc.target(BASEURL);
    return target.proxy(RiskScapeLicenseService.class);
    Response response = client.getExpiredLicenses();
    assertTrue(HttpResponseCodes.SC_OK == response.getStatus());
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    JAXBElement<LicenseList> element = (JAXBElement<LicenseList>) response.getEntity();
    LicenseList list = element.getValue();
    assertEquals(4, list.getLicenses().size());
    for (License lic : list.getLicenses()) {
      assertTrue((new Date()).after(DateUtils.parseDate(lic.getValidTo(), new String[] { "yyyy-MM-dd" })));
    }
  }
```

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>riskscapelic_rest</display-name>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

The LicenseList class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "LicenseList")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "licenseList", propOrder = {
    "licenses"
})
public class LicenseList {

    @XmlElement(name = "Licenses", required = true)
    protected List<License> licenses;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the licenses property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
     * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
     * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
     * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the licenses property.
     * 
     * <p>
     * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
     * <pre>
     *    getLicenses().add(newItem);
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     * <p>
     * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
     * {@link License }
     * 
     * 
     */
    public List<License> getLicenses() {
        if (licenses == null) {
            licenses = new ArrayList<License>();
        }
        return this.licenses;
    }

}
```

I am using JDK 1.7, Tomcat 7.0.47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've resolved my issue by updating my schema with jaxb:version="2.0"
and regenerating the jaxb classes. The tip off was someone's mention of there being a
Resteasy Client -> JAX-RS 2.0 mismatch migration problem.
Also to note that in this jaxb version, the XmlRootElementis still being omitted by the genearator, So it needs to be added to all the classes that are being used as inputs for POST requests